# Cloud server advice for storing and managing files with user permissions

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, file-sharing

We are a little company with 15 workers. We work with invoices and files in common with PDF and Word extensions. For now our office workers work with local Windows shared folders but that computer was damaged and we lost most of our files. How and what service can we work with to store our files by folders and add users with permissions for our workers? I need your advice please. Google Cloud or AWS or something else?

Answer (score 1):

AWS and Google will both have products that would work, but they're complex enterprise products that take knowledge and experience to set up. Based on your question I think you want / need a simpler solution.

Something more consumer / end user oriented such as OneDrive / Dropbox / Google Drive might be more suitable for you. You would have to look into user permissions, but most of these products will support some kind of user permissions.

Make sure your selected product has either a backup, recovery or file versioning / history features. You need to protect against someone accidentally deleting the files, viruses, malware, etc.

Comment: If they are already using Office 365 OneDrive may also be an option and there are a few 3rd parties that provide backup for O365 services.

Comment: Yeah OneDrive makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sharepoint in Office 365 to store your files and control access to those files.